# C# Problem with Generics

Tags: c#, generics

**What I have?**

I have an abstract class, `QueryExecutor` and derived class, `SqlQueryExecutor` shown below.

```
abstract class QueryExecutor<T>
{
    public abstract T Execute();
}

class SqlQueryExecutor<T> : QueryExecutor<T> where T:ICollection
{
    public override T Execute()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        // Do common stuff
        if (type == typeof(ProfileNodeCollection))
        {
            ProfileNodeCollection nodes = new ProfileNodeCollection();
            // Logic to build nodes
            return (T)nodes;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNodeCollection nodes = new TreeNodeCollection();
            Logic to build nodes

            return (T)nodes;                
        }
    }
}
```

**What I want to do?**

In the implementation of `Execute()` method, I want to construct the appropriate `ICollection` object and return it.

**What problem am I facing?**

In `Execute()` method, the line, `return (T)nodes;` shows the following compile time error:

> Cannot convert type 'WebAppTest.ProfileNodeCollection' to 'T'

Any idea how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you already asked this question an hour ago: Design Problem - Common base class and different return types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605659/design-problem-common-base-class-and-different-return-types

Comment: I'm not sure why the problem is arising, but that's such an abuse of generics that I don't want to answer anyway... The whole point of generics is that they should be *generic* and shouldn't contain special behaviour for different concrete types of `T` (see the Liskov Substitution Principle for more details). If you're doing this type of thing you'd be better off with `ProfileNodeCollectionQueryExecutor` and `TreeNodeCollectionQueryExecutor` as separate classes (i.e. if your situation requires polymorphism, then use it).

Comment: @ Mitch Wheat: I tried to implement the answer to the previous question and got struck here. Thought of updating the same question but, I had marked it as answered. So, created another question. Though, this question is about implementation part of the previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a simple way of fixing it is to just make the compiler *less* aware of what's going on, so that it'll just defer it to the CLR:

```
return (T)(object)nodes;
```

You could put this in a single place and use an implicit conversion to `object` on assignment:

```
object ret;
// Do common stuff
if (type == typeof(ProfileNodeCollection))
{
    ProfileNodeCollection nodes = new ProfileNodeCollection();
    // Logic to build nodes
    ret = nodes;
}
else
{
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = new TreeNodeCollection();
    Logic to build nodes

    ret = nodes;
}
return (T)ret;
```

It's not terribly pleasant, but it should work. It would probably be nicer to create separate derived classes for different collection types though - possibly putting common code in an abstract base class.

Answer (score 1):

I would chose to separate concerns here. You could even have a `QueryExecutor` factory that would provide the right `QueryExecutor` accordingly to the type of collection.

```
class ProfileSqlQueryExecutor : QueryExecutor<ProfileNodeCollection>
{
    public override ProfileNodeCollection Execute()
    {
        ProfileNodeCollection nodes = new ProfileNodeCollection();
        // Logic to build nodes
        return nodes;
    }
}

class TreeSqlQueryExecutor : QueryExecutor<TreeNodeCollection>
{
    public override TreeNodeCollection Execute()
    {
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = new TreeNodeCollection();
        Logic to build nodes
        return nodes;                
    }
}
```